# What is the best VBox network configuration scheme for reaching a network adapter?

Tags: networking, virtualbox

Maybe my question can appear trivial, but I am completly lost with all the available network configurations in Virtual Box.

My problem is as follow, I have an hardware with a static IP adress 192.168.0.80, I have a Host computer (running Win7), and a guest OS in a virtual box (Ubuntu).

I would like to ping the hardware (with static IP address) from the guest OS.

The following picture describe my configuration :
[image]

Of course, when I configure Host.eth0 with a static IP address like 192.168.0.1, I can ping my hardware.
But now :
**What kind of network configuration should I select in virtual box to be able to ping my hardware with the guest OS ? NAT ? Bridge ?**

Any good reference to what are these configurations is very welcom.

Answer (score 1):

For such configuration, a bridged interface on the interface of the host connected to the network is the best choice, as your guest OS will appear as a physical one.

More on that : https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#networkingmodes

**Edit** : note that the NAT mode will allow you to easily access the Internet for example, but will present limitations when you want to access your guest from the outside, as you will have to add network redirections, based on ports rules.